# C# Functions With Overloaded Methods

Tags: c#

Okay, to show what my code looks like (and this works, but isn't necessarily pretty):

```
    public delegate Response Func<R1>(ref R1 out1);
    public delegate Response Func<T1, R1>(T1 in1, ref R1 out1);
    public delegate Response Func<T1, T2, R1>(T1 in1, T2 in2, ref R1 out1);
    public delegate Response Func<T1, T2, T3, R1>(T1 in1, T2 in2, T3 in3, ref R1 out1);
    public delegate Response Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, R1>(T1 in1, T2 in2, T3 in3, T4 in4, ref R1 out1);
    public delegate Response Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, R1>(T1 in1, T2 in2, T3 in3, T4 in4, T5 in5, ref R1 out1);
    public delegate Response Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, R1>(T1 in1, T2 in2, T3 in3, T4 in4, T5 in5, T6 in6, ref R1 out1);


    public static Response Query<R1>(Func<R1> method, ref R1 out1)
    {
        return QueryAll<object, object, object, object, object, object, R1>(method, null, null, null, null, null, null, ref out1);
    }

    public static Response Query<T1, R1>(Func<T1, R1> method, T1 in1, ref R1 out1)
    {
        return QueryAll<T1, object, object, object, object, object, R1>(method, in1, null, null, null, null, null, ref out1);
    }

    public static Response Query<T1, T2, R1>(Func<T1, T2, R1> method, T1 in1, T2 in2, ref R1 out1)
    {
        return QueryAll<T1, T2, object, object, object, object, R1>(method, in1, in2, null, null, null, null, ref out1);
    }

    public static Response Query<T1, T2, T3, R1>(Func<T1, T2, T3, R1> method, T1 in1, T2 in2, T3 in3, ref R1 out1)
    {
        return QueryAll<T1, T2, T3, object, object, object, R1>(method, in1, in2, in3, null, null, null, ref out1);
    }

    public static Response Query<T1, T2, T3, T4, R1>(Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, R1> method, T1 in1, T2 in2, T3 in3, T4 in4, ref R1 out1)
    {
        return QueryAll<T1, T2, T3, T4, object, object, R1>(method, in1, in2, in3, in4, null, null, ref out1);
    }

    public static Response Query<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, R1>(Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, R1> method, T1 in1, T2 in2, T3 in3, T4 in4, T5 in5, ref R1 out1)
    {
        return QueryAll<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, object, R1>(method, in1, in2, in3, in4, in5, null, ref out1);
    }

    public static Response Query<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, R1>(Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, R1> method, T1 in1, T2 in2, T3 in3, T4 in4, T5 in5, T6 in6, ref R1 out1)
    {
        return QueryAll<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, R1>(method, in1, in2, in3, in4, in5, in6, ref out1);
    }

    private static Response QueryAll<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, R1>(Delegate method, T1 in1, T2 in2, T3 in3, T4 in4, T5 in5, T6 in6, ref R1 out1)
    {
        try
        {
            Response response = null;

            // Test if the method's class implements ICacheable
            if (method.GetType() is ICacheable)
            {
                // Try to get the value from the cache if available
                out1 = ((ICacheable)method.Target).Get<R1>(out1);

                // If not null, return the value and exit
                if (out1 != null)
                    return null;
                else
                {
                    // Value is null, but should be cached, so attempt to load to cache and return it
                    if (in6 != null)
                        response = ((Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, R1>)method)(in1, in2, in3, in4, in5, in6, ref out1);
                    else if (in5 != null)
                        response = ((Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, R1>)method)(in1, in2, in3, in4, in5, ref out1);
                    else if (in4 != null)
                        response = ((Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, R1>)method)(in1, in2, in3, in4, ref out1);
                    else if (in3 != null)
                        response = ((Func<T1, T2, T3, R1>)method)(in1, in2, in3, ref out1);
                    else if (in2 != null)
                        response = ((Func<T1, T2, R1>)method)(in1, in2, ref out1);
                    else if (in1 != null)
                        response = ((Func<T1, R1>)method)(in1, ref out1);
                    else
                        response = ((Func<R1>)method)(ref out1);

                    // If value from database is not null, save it in cache
                    if (out1 != null)
                        ((ICacheable)method.Target).Set<R1>(out1);

                    return response;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Get data from database
                if (in6 != null)
                    response = ((Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, R1>)method)(in1, in2, in3, in4, in5, in6, ref out1);
                else if (in5 != null)
                    response = ((Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, R1>)method)(in1, in2, in3, in4, in5, ref out1);
                else if (in4 != null)
                    response = ((Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, R1>)method)(in1, in2, in3, in4, ref out1);
                else if (in3 != null)
                    response = ((Func<T1, T2, T3, R1>)method)(in1, in2, in3, ref out1);
                else if (in2 != null)
                    response = ((Func<T1, T2, R1>)method)(in1, in2, ref out1);
                else if (in1 != null)
                    response = ((Func<T1, R1>)method)(in1, ref out1);
                else
                    response = ((Func<R1>)method)(ref out1);

                return response;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            CustomException exception = exc.ToCustomException();
            exception.Code = ResponseCodes.UnknownError;
            throw exception;
        }
    }
```

This is the data abstraction layer.  Again, my question is I want to allow a developer to pass in a method and up to 6 parameters.  But, I only want one main method to contain all of my logic so that it's easier to maintain.  Then, based on certain conditions (is the object in cache or not), call a method on the data layer to read in the object from the repository, store in cache, then return object to the controller.

Is there a better way to do this than multiple if/else statements like below?

Comment: You might look into the `params` keyword, but I'm not sure if what you want is possible.

Comment: C# unfortunately doesn't have the mechanisms to make this nicer and type safe.  It doesn't have variadic generics, delegates don't have a common interface, you'll just have to resort to solutions like this or sacrifice type safety and use reflection or build up dynamic expressions.

Comment: I don't think there is any reasonable way to do this. Might want to rephrase your question a little though cause I found it kind of confusing. I could post an idea that centralizes this logic but it is a work around. The concept is to make a type that has a field for each possible arg, use a static initializer to instantiate it then have a single `Query` method on the type which you call and it has all the if/else logic to select which method to invoke based on the nullity of it's properties. I would say it's far from ideal but I don't know how else you would get that level of flexibility.

Comment: This is very possible. Its no different than the linq problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have your business logic contained in another method, that has an argument for the method you want to call

```
public static Response Query<R1>(Func<Tuple<Result, R1>> method, ref R1 @out)
{
    Tuple<Result, R1> result = Logic(() => method());
    @out = result.Item2;
    return result.Item1;
}

public static Response Query<T1, R1>(Func<T1, Tuple<Result, R1>> method, T1 a, ref R1 @out)
{
    Tuple<Result, R1> result = Logic(() => method(a));
    @out = result.Item2;
    return result.Item1;
}

public static Response Query<T1, T2, R1>(Func<T1, T2, Tuple<Result, R1>> method, T1 a, T2 b, ref R1 @out)
{
    Tuple<Result, R1> result = Logic(() => method(a, b));
    @out = result.Item2;
    return result.Item1;
}

...

public static Tuple<Result, R1> Logic<R1>(Func<Tuple<Result, R1>> doMethod)
{
    Tuple<Result, R1> result;
    // logic
    if(true) { result = doMethod(); }
    ...

    // watch out if this doesn't get assigned, can cause problems downstream
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your code.  Method has a ref parameter *and* returns a value.  So doMethod should be something like response = doMethod(ref @out);

Comment: that works too. it doesn't terribly matter, but you should be able to dynamically pass the method that needs to be called, in a wrapper Func that can be passed to the Logic(). That way that method can be invoked by the passed Func in the Logic(). If you provided a bit more code, I could come up with a better answer.

Comment: the problem is, you're assuming that all three Query methods are calling an overloaded version of a method *called* 'Method'.  That's not the case.  I need to pass in the method and its parameters in to the Query method.  That's why I'm using the Func<> parameter in my Query methods.

Comment: then pass the invocation of that method via the Func doMethod into the business logic. I'll update to reflect this

Comment: your code is the same as PetSerAl's answer.  My issue is I need "doMethod()" to return an object AND a ref parameter.  Your code only has it returning the object.  For this reason I had to create my custom delegates above because the System.Func doesn't accept ref params by default.

Comment: That's because your code only had it returning a single value. I recommend having your Func return a Tuple<Response, R1> so that you can return 2 things in 1 value. Do you need code for that?

Comment: that would help.  Also, I've edited original question to give you context of what I have right now.  My code does work, but I'm looking for a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What if instead putting T1, T2, and the others as separate parameters you would put them in a list? `List<object>`

You would get something similar to this:

```
public static Response Query<L1,R1>(L1 in1, ref R1 out1)
{
    // The SAME business logic with the same if/then statements
    if (true)
        out1 = method(in1, in2);
    else
        // Some other business logic
}
```

There would be no need to pass `method` as a parameter as it would always take the same list and the same number of parameters.

Then you'd perform the same operations in `method` by checking `in1.Count` and the type of each individual item: `if (typeof(in1[0]) == T1) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ohmusama!  I tweaked your code a bit because I needed to still use the returned reference parameter in my Generic query method, but you helped a ton!

Below is my final answer with one overloaded method:

```
    public static Response Query<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, R1>(Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, Tuple<Response, R1>> method, T1 in1, T2 in2, T3 in3, T4 in4, T5 in5, T6 in6, ref R1 out1)
    {
        return QueryAll(() => method(in1, in2, in3, in4, in5, in6), ref out1);
    }

    private static Response QueryAll<R1>(Func<Tuple<Response, R1>> method, ref R1 out1)
    {
        try
        {
            Tuple<Response, R1> result;

            // Test if the method's class implements ICacheable
            if (method.GetType() is ICacheable)
            {
                // Try to get the value from the cache if available
                out1 = ((ICacheable)method.Target).Get<R1>(out1);

                // If not null, return the value and exit
                if (out1 != null)
                    return null;
                else
                {
                    // Value is null, but should be cached, so attempt to load to cache and return it
                    result = method();
                    out1 = result.Item2;

                    // If value from database is not null, save it in cache
                    if (out1 != null)
                        ((ICacheable)method.Target).Set<R1>(out1);

                    return result.Item1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Get data from database
                result = method();
                out1 = result.Item2;

                return result.Item1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            CustomException exception = exc.ToCustomException();
            exception.Code = ResponseCodes.UnknownError;
            throw exception;
        }
    }
```